# How to get CPU usage from "top" and save it to file - MAC OS bash

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I am using the terminal in MAC OS. I want to get on only the total ideal CPU from the top command (just ideal cpu) and stor it to a file.

I have tried this:
`top | grep -w "CPU usage: "`
And i got this :

```
/Test/temp1 » top | grep "CPU usage: "                                                130 ↵
CPU usage: 5.45% user, 11.77% sys, 82.77% idle 
CPU usage: 3.20% user, 3.51% sys, 93.27% idle 
CPU usage: 2.64% user, 2.76% sys, 94.59% idle 
CPU usage: 3.18% user, 2.61% sys, 94.19% idle
```

.

I want to store only the last metrics en every line which is "82.77% idle" but without the "% and idel" word, only I want the amount of ideal CPU to store it in a file.
Ex:

```
82.77 
93.27 
94.59 
94.19
```

I appreciate your help ,,,

Comment: You could pipe grep's output to `sed 's/.*\s\([0-9.]*\)%.*/\1/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `grep` and `awk` to get the required number alone. Here the `--line-buffered` flag is used, which forces grep to write to the output each time a new line is encountered.

```
top | grep --line-buffered "CPU usage: " |awk '{ print substr($5, 1, length($5)-1) }'
```

Or you could directly use awk

```
top | awk '/^CPU usage: / { print substr($5, 1, length($5)-1) }'
```

Comment: `grep` is never needed when you're piping to awk. `awk '/CPU usage: / { print substr($5, 1, length($5)-1) }'`